# How to deploy from sandbox to production in salesforce?

Tags: force.com, deployment

We are currently working in a sandbox in salesforce . Now i want to know how i can switch to production environment in salesforce ?

Comment: You need to log in to the `login.salesforce.com` with your username and password.

Comment: Do you mean move functionality to production ? It may be good if you update your question to explain what you mean by "switch".

Comment: Yes i want to move with functionality

Comment: @Amit Can you elaborate your question you are willing to move your objects,clasees from sandbox to production..??

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce offers a lot of documentation on this subject. Start here:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dev_lifecycle/index_Left.htm#CSHID=migrate.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fmigrate.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Here is another article with 2 videos about different deployment methods:
http://www.oyecode.com/2012/07/how-to-deploy-salesforce-apex-code-to.html

The 2 deployment methods mentioned are:

- Use salesforce Change sets (as an administrator, from the Salesforce Setup pages)
- Use the Salesforce migration toolkit, using the Metadata API (requires technical knowledge or additional tools such as the Mavensmate or Eclipse IDEs)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to login to your prod org by going to the
url  :- http://login.salesforce.com

enter your credentials and login 
since you have to move your data from sandbox to production 
hence in sandbox you have to make outbound change set and in production you have to make inbound change set 
Change set is the customization/code you want to deploy to production .
once you select the outbound change set in sandbox click upload make sure that you have selected all of the dependencies and profiles 
once you upload it to production go to the production org and click on inbound change set and deploy.

Note :- If you are deploying the Apex code your organization must include 75% code to deploy .